# GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT FOR GOOGLE DRIVE PLS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Good morning everyone, I hope you can help me, I am trying to create a Script in Google Drive, what happens is that every time I add a new email to a certain folder, this email is automatically deleted within 1 month, I have created this code but it doesn't work

```
function deleteEmailsFromFolder(folder) {
  var deadline = new Date();
  deadline.setMinutes(deadline.getMinutes() - 1);
  
  var files;
  
  try {
    files = folder.getFiles();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Failed to access files in the folder.");
  }
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var creationDate = file.getDateCreated();
    
    if (creationDate < deadline) {
      DriveApp.removeFile(file);
    }
  }
}

function searchFolderByName(name, parentFolder) {
  var folders = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(name);
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    deleteEmailsFromFolder(folder);
  }
}

function deleteEmailsFromSpecificFolder() {
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1yCUif2AfEtdQp5vp5WS9E_naFAwSYux7"); // Replace "PARENT_FOLDER_ID" with the actual parent folder ID
  var folderName = "Cooking tutorials"; // Replace "FOLDER_NAME" with the specific folder name
  
  searchFolderByName(folderName, parentFolder);
}

deleteEmailsFromSpecificFolder();
```

I have tried for a long time to modify the code to make it work and I have not succeeded

Comment: Why  do you store emails in a Drive Folder.  I store them in email folders

Comment: define doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function deleteEmailsFromFolder(folder) {
  var deadline = new Date().valueOf();
  deadline.setMinutes(deadline.getMinutes() - 1);
  
  var files;
  
  try {
    files = folder.getFiles();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Failed to access files in the folder.");
  }
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var creationDate = file.getDateCreated().valueOf();
    
    if (creationDate < deadline) {
      Drive.Files.remove(file.getId()); //need to enable Drive API
    }
  }
}
```